# ORA-01843: not a valid month error

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-comparison

I have a column in Oracle DB which is `varchar2` data type. Typical value stored in this column is like `06/16/2015 02:14:18 AM`. 
I am trying to get all records wherein this column is having records after 1st August 2015.

```
select * 
from MYTABLE 
where to_date(substr(MYCOLUMN,1,10),'dd-mm-yyyy') > to_date('01-08-2015','dd-mm-yyyy');
```

But, I am getting `ORA-01843`. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The format in the column: `06/16/2015 02:14:18 AM` does not match the format mask `dd-mm-yyyy` that you use in your `to_date()` call on that column. You want `mm/dd/yyyy` instead

Comment: Your patter is wrong: ´'dd-mm-yyyy'` must be `mm/'dd/yyyy'`

Comment: Why do you store `DATE` as `VARCHAR2`? Using appropriate data type is one of the most important part of database design and performance.

Comment: That column was created long back. Changing data type of that column now, will add too much of other overheads.

Comment: @user2488578 *Changing data type of that column now, will add too much of other overheads.* Believe me, sooner or later you will have to do it. It's never too late to fix the design issue first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respect the format in your VARCHAR

```
....where to_date(substr(MYCOLUMN,1,10),'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I am getting the same error if I add order by ..`select * from MYTABLE where to_date(substr(MYCOLUMN,1,10),'mm/dd/yyyy') > to_date('08/01/2015','mm/dd/yyyy')
 order by SOMEOTHERCOLUMN desc;`

Answer (score 1):

> I have a column in Oracle DB which is varchar2 data type. Typical value stored in this column is like 06/16/2015 02:14:18 AM.

The first question is why do you store **DATE** as **string**? Using appropriate **data type** is one of the most important part of **database design** and **performance**.

Understand that **DATE** doesn't have the **format** you see, it is internally stored in `7 bytes` which is Oracle's proprietary  format. Storing date as a **string** to have a fixed format is not recommended.

I would suggest first fix the design so that you don't have to do this overhead activity while **comparing dates**. In the longer run it will help you.

**1. Add a new column as DATE data type.**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
   ADD new_column DATE;
```

**2. Update the new column.**

```
UPDATE table_name 
   SET new_column = TO_DATE(old_column, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss pm');
```

**3. DROP the old column.**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
   DROP COLUMN old_column;
```

**4. Rename the new column to old column name.**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name;
```

Now, you could compare dates easily:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE mycolumn > to_date('01-08-2015','dd-mm-yyyy');
```

This will also use any regular **index** on the date column.

**From performance point of view**:

If you don't fix it now, you will keep facing performance issues. Because the immediate fix of `SUBSTR` will not let you use any regular **index**, you need to create a **function-based index**.

Answer (score 0):

If in your table all values like `06/16/2015 02:14:18 AM` then you can use `trunc(to_date(MYCOLUMN,'mm/dd/yyyy HH:mi:SS PM'),'dd')` against `to_date(substr(MYCOLUMN,1,10),'dd-mm-yyyy')`.